# Employer allows an entitlement vs Employer includes an entitlement

Tags: sentence-construction

> Employers often offer employees perks in addition to cash wages, for example, membership of a health insurance or company pension
> scheme
> If they do, they must
> ensure
> that they are fair in providing these benefits in order to
> avoid
> discrimination. For instance, if an employer
> **allows/includes**
> an entitlement to low-interest loans in male, but not female, employees' contracts, the female employees could take the employer to court on the basis of unequal
> treatment

I am unable to understand the difference between which word to use in the given context

Can anyone guide me about the same?
Thanks in advance.

**My Approach:**

I found some meanings for the words but unable to understand the usage in the given paragraph.

allow --> permit / give the necessary time

include --> add/cover

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These two words would both be acceptable. To make a distinction between the two, you have to look at the root meaning. Which is more "accurate" is all about context. The difference is between the employer putting the entitlement in voluntarily without prompting, and the employer putting the entitlement in as a concession to someone else. Aka if the employer drafts the contracts and puts the entitlement in on their own without input from anyone else, they have "included" it. But if the employer puts the entitlement in as a result of some direct or anticipated pressure or input from someone else, then they have also "allowed" it. The fact they have "allowed" it, however, does not make "included" incorrect, since in this second situation they have done both.

The term "allowed" tends to put some emphasis on the employer having opinions about things, whereas "included" is more neutral, and just serves to let you know that they put it in the contract.